# Flutter exam answer selection

Tags: flutter

im building an exam app but i have a problem.

when i choose an answer its colored red as i want but when scroll to next question, question that i answered is turns not answered.

i cant find out how to build this exam system

this is my button

```
int selected = 0;
  Widget customRadio(String text, int index) {
    return RaisedButton(
      color:
          (selected == index) ? Colors.red : ColorConstants.instance.foreColor,
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          selected = index;
        });
      },
      child: Text(
        text,
      ),
    );
  }
```

this is my question and answer block (send it to listview.builder and populate with firestore)

```
//...question text...//


 child: ListView(
                children: [
                  customRadio("Biraz kapamak", 1),
                  customRadio("Büzmek, daraltmak", 2),
                  customRadio("Azaltmak, alçaltmak", 3),
                  customRadio("Yatıştırmak", 4),
                  customRadio("Eksiltmek, sınırlandırmak", 5),
                ],
              ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question and answers should be set in models
Like

```
    class Answer{
    String? value;
    bool selected = false;
    }
    
    class QuestionAnswers{
    String? question;
    List<Answer>? answers;

selectAnswer(Answer answer){
//TODO: set all answers to false, except this one
}
    }
```

So you will populate the listwidget with it. Then when you select one answer, set its selected to true to persist it temporarily.

Then your custom button should be painted according to the answer's state.